# What is the file format for JUnit5's test discovery?

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I've been dynamically generating TestNG xml suites in a project I'm working on. In an effort to take some initiative in migrating to JUnit5. The TestNG specification is [very easy to find](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml), but I cannot find the equivalent for JUnit5.

All I can find are reference that a file or uri can be specified for test discovery. Either by [command line option or URI](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher-options) and again under the [configuring selectors section](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-gradle-selectors).

Naively, I'd like to assume that it's just the `fully.qualified.package.ClassName#methodName` format because I can find this as an example in the [MethodSelector](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/platform/engine/discovery/DiscoverySelectors.html#selectMethod-java.lang.String-). The [UriSelctor](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/platform/engine/discovery/DiscoverySelectors.html#selectUri-java.lang.String-) and [FileSelector](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/platform/engine/discovery/DiscoverySelectors.html#selectFile-java.io.File-) don't show what the actually expected format of the document is supposed to look like.

Comment: The possibility to specify a file, directory or URI for test discovery is meant for test engines that operate on files instead of classes, e.g. Cucumber. There's currently no support to specify in a file which tests should be run. Please chime in on https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/744 and add the feature request to declare a suite via a file.

Comment: Thanks, @MarcPhilipp. Now that the holidays are through I've done just that here: [https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1243](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1243)